# How to combine custom panels with splom() (or xyplot() or pairs())

Tags: r, panel, lattice

I'm having trouble combining heterogenous panels with lattice package tools. I tried `splom()`, `pairs()`, and `xyplot()`, but unsuccessfully so far. Suppose I have a simple time series data of 3 columns as `xts` object:

```
library(xts)
S = as.xts(apply(matrix(rnorm(300), ,3), 2, cumsum), Sys.Date()+1:100)
```

1. **Diagonal panels** (top left to bottom right or `diag(5)` format) need to show 3 density plots, one for each series.
2. **Upper triangular panels** need to show `latticeExtra::densityplot` (or equivalently `panel.densityplot`) for the three series. The order doesn't matter for now; I'll work it out later.
3. **Lower triangular panels** need to show horizontal box plots. I suppose `panel.bwplot` would work, but could not successfully tame it.

Here is a skeleton of what may work, but I'll be thankful for any successful version.

```
library(lattice); library(latticeExtra)

splom(as.data.frame(S),
      upper.panel=function(){
        panel.abline() # temporary placeholder
      },
      diag.panel = function(x, ...){
        yrng <- current.panel.limits()$ylim
        d <- density(x, na.rm=TRUE)
        d$y <- with(d, yrng[1] + 0.95 * diff(yrng) * y / max(y) )
        panel.lines(d)
        diag.panel.splom(x, ...)
      },
      lower.panel = function(x, y, ...){
        panel.abline()  # temporary placeholder
      },
      pscale=0, as.matrix = TRUE
)
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to do here. `splom` plots scatterplot matrices, i.e., plots of two variables but you're trying to plot density plots and boxplots, which are plots of one variable.